# Mapping vs. Setting color in Discrete vs. Continuous case

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot. I am trying to understand how to use ggplot. I am reading Wickham's book and still trying to wrap my head around mapping vs. setting color.

**A) Discrete case**
Here's what I did:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
test<-filter(mpg,year==2008)
    test<-test[1:10,]
    grid <- data_frame(displ = seq(min(mpg$displ), max(mpg$displ), length = 50))
    mod <- loess(hwy ~ displ, data = mpg)
    grid$hwy <- predict(mod, newdata = grid)
```

a) Use discrete values and then use (aes(color = "xyz"))

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(displ,hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = test,aes(label=trans,color = "blue"))
```

This just adds a legend with the label "blue". Why does this happen?

b) Supply color = "blue" outside of aesthetics.

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(displ,hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = test,aes(label=trans),color = "blue")
```

This works and changes the color to "blue".

**B) Continuous case**

a) Use (aes(color = "xyz"))
Here's what I did:

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(displ,hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = grid, aes(colour = "green"),size=1.5)
```

As with the case a) for discrete case, this adds a pink line with the text "green"

b) Supply color outside of aesthetics.

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(displ,hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = grid, colour = "green",size=1.5)
```

Here, the color of the line does change to "Green" and I have lost the label.

So, I am not understanding the value of aes(colour = "xyz"). All it does is that add a label. Isn't it? Why would we use it?

Comment: Short answer: you shouldn't ever use `aes(colour = 'xyz')`. I can't think of a good reason to use it other than to illustrate why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Gregor, well you can use that, if `'xyz'` is not the name of a color but a label. Like `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(color = 'this is a loess function'))`.

Comment: Yes, you can. I suppose it's a fine way to label layers that don't map well to aesthetics, extending your example to say, `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(aes(color = "loess")) +
    geom_smooth(method = 'lm', aes(color = 'lm'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data - data columns or transformations of data columns, go inside `aes()`. When you do `aes(color = 'blue')`, it's as if your data had an unnamed column that had the character string `"blue"` in every row.

```
ggplot(mpg,aes(displ,hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = test, aes(label = trans, color = "blue"))
```

In this context, `"blue"` is not a color - it is just a character string. You will get an identical result (except for the label) if you use `color = "green",`, `color = "bleu"`, or `color = "look at this long long label"` - if these are inside `aes()`.

A character string - even if it only has one value - will be coerced to a factor and treated as a discrete variable.

*This can be confusing if you don't follow the general rule:* **don't put constants inside `aes()` - only put mappings to actual data columns.**

You seem to be confused about continuous vs discrete color scales. What you label as "continuous case" is still discrete when it comes to color. Using `geom_point` or `geom_line`, a smoothed geom, or any other geom *doesn't make color discrete or continuous*. The only thing that matters for choosing a discrete or continuous color scale is the type (`class`) of data that is mapped to color. If it is numeric, the default color scale will be continuous. If it is not numeric, the default color scale will be discrete.

Comment: I agree completely with this. Just to add though, the examples will work with `scale_color_identity()`.